# Como colocar uma variável específica em Session

Tags: php

Galera, primeiro olá a todos!!
Eu to com uma dúvida,

Preciso colocar uma variável com o URL da página específica em Session, pra que seja usado em várias páginas posteriores.
O código que to usando pra pegar a URl é esse

```
$URL_PAG = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

Mas não consegui colocar isso em Session sem que ela mude nas página posteriores.
Alguém poderia me dar uma luz, de como devo prosseguir?

Comment: Como assim mude? Ela pega a url da outra página?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/sessionhandler.write.php

Comment: Olha minha resposta, aqui funcionou

Comment: De forma resumida, eu upo uma imagem e quero usar a URL dela em session, eu não tava conseguindo usar a URL em session, mas o querido Woton Sampaio ajudou demais.

Answer (score -1):

Tenta fazer uma constante:

```
session_start();

define("nome", "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");

$_SESSION['url'] = nome;
```

Comment: Perfeito, deu certinho, muito obrigado!

Comment: @JonataSantos de nada, se quiser aceitar minha resposta eu também agradeço :3 kkkkk